# Is there a way to obtain this font for the chapter numbering?

Tags: fonts

I saw this font in the following picture:

[image]

Can you suggest something to make it usable for the chapter numbers in a (La)TeX document?

Comment: I'd say 'Dosis' is quite near. In this case you would need to use the LuaTeX or XeTeX engine since there is only an open type version of it.

Comment: Really thanks @Ruben ... Dosis is font family?

Comment: You're welcome @juanuni, and yes Dosis is the font family. You can see it here, for instance: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dosis

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, it looks like what I want, but I dont like having to use LuaTeX or XeTeX engine :S ...

Comment: @juanuni - Any particular reason for disliking having to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?

Comment: Well I'm using `kpfonts` and `fontenc` packages ...

Comment: @Ruben the font in chapter numbering is `Dezen Stencil 02` ...